# Ember Data Save - Laravel not receiving data

Tags: javascript, php, ember.js

Ember model:

```
App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
            description: DS.attr('string'),
            duration: DS.attr('string'),
            company:DS.attr('string'),
            project:DS.attr('string')
        });
```

Then in my controller I am saving the new instance of the Object:

```
task = this.store.createRecord('task',{
                        description:'ff',
                        duration:'zz',
                        company: 'aa',
                        project: 'dd'
                    });
```

And attempting to save it:

```
task.save().then(console.log('saving')).catch(console.log('errr'));
```

This hits right controller in my Laravel code, but I tried to

```
die(var_dump($_POST))
```

and to

```
die(var_dump($_REQUEST))
```

But the data is never there. How can I get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching I found that I had to

```
$task = $request->get('task')
```

in the laravel code (as per http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input)

That contained the array of data I was looking for.